# Accessing Prestashop webservice, PHP Curl gets 401 Unauthorized access, but works in browser

Tags: php, curl, prestashop-1.7

I am using PrestaShopWebservice library to access Prestashiop 1.7 Webservice, I always `get 401 Unauthorized` but it is accessible in browser.

I have already tried adding:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

in `.htaccess`
also tried concatenating `&ws_key="token"`

but nothing works

```
 $url = 'http://someurl/api/';
 $token = 'mytoken';
 try {
    $webService = new \PrestaShopWebservice($url, $token, true);
    $xml = $webService->get(['resource'=>'products']);
    var_dump($xml);
 }
 catch (\PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: After reading some other forum posts:

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/442699-webservice-in-16-give-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized/

It might seem to be domain issue?  I'm gonna try a local test first.

Comment: I can't make it work on local also, it also works on browser but does not work when using php curl, but this time error is bad request